# Symfony3 Doctrine querybuilder

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

I am writing Symfony3 app using Doctrine ORM.

I have a entity with all my attributes and their setters and getters.

Trying to build so that i can retrieve a row based on a email address.

```
my query:

      /**
     * @param $email
     */
    public function getUserByEmail($email)
{
    $repository = $this->db->EntityManagerORM()
        ->getRepository('TestBundle:User');

    $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->where('t.emial = :email')
        ->setParameter(':email', $email)
        ->getQuery();

    $test = $query->getResult();

    var_dump($test);
```

1. $this->db is a EntityManager which is a service and instantiated in my __construct. so what i do is retrieve the entity, they create a queryBuilder where i want to retrieve a entire row which email == to the given email.

   response I get:

   ```
   "Notice: Undefined index: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 63 near 'emial
   ```

   = :ema': Error: Class Test\TestBundle\Entity\User has no field or

   association named emial"

anything suspicious in my code....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's the spelling of email. Change to this:

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('t')
      ->where('t.email = :email')
      ->setParameter(':email', $email)
      ->getQuery();
```

That should fix the problem.

Comment: OMG I feel slightly embarrassed :P but thank you for spotting it. this was the only issue.

Comment: No problem, often we need another person just to help us look over our code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for `:` in **setParameter** function.

Another thing wrong in your code is, the User table has no column with the name `emial`. Double check and replace it with appropriate name.

So your query will look something like this,

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->where('t.RIGHT_COLUMN_NAME = :email')
        ->setParameter('email', $email)
        ->getQuery();
```

In above code replace `RIGHT_COLUMN_NAME` with the correct column name.

Comment: and : i just add to to differentiate parameter from table.column, so the code is more readable